# Easiest way to display Django model data in html

Tags: python, django, model

I have data being stored in a Django model, and I want to display that data in my HTML file. What is the easiest way that I could do this? I am familiar with [this][1] question, but it does not help me because it is not very detailed and does not have a definite answer. Can someone please help me? My code is down below.

---

Django Model:

```
class userdetails(models.Model):
  donations = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null = True,)
  points = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null = True,)
  user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
```

HTML where I want to display data from the model:

```
<div class="box">
                   <span class="value"> </span>  
                   <span class="parameter">Points</span>
                </div>
```

This is my view:

```
    @login_required(login_url='/login/')
def dashboard(request):
    id = request.user.id
    data= userdetails.objects.get(id=id)
    return render(request,'dashboard.html',{'data':data})
```

The error I keep getting:

```
DoesNotExist at /dashboard/
userdetails matching query does not exist.
```

Has something to do with `data= userdetails.objects.get(id=id)` in my views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to create a view  to retreive the data you need from your model :

views.py :

```
from .models import userdetails
from django.shortcuts import render

def get_data(request):

    my_data = userdetails.objects.all() #for all the records 
    one_data = userdetails.objects.get(pk=1) # 1 will return the first item change it depending on the data you want 
    context={
       
      'my_data':my_data,
      'one_data':one_data,
    
    } 

    return render(request, 'get_data.html', context)
```

add the the view to urls.py :

url.py :

```
from .views import get_data

urlpatterns = [

path('get_data/', get_data, name='get_data'),
```

]

create get_data.html in the templates folder :

get_data.html : for the list

```
{% block content %}

{% for x in my_data %}

  {{x.name }}
{% endfor %}

{% endblock content %}
```

for the item :

```
 {% block content %}



  {{one_data}}


{% endblock content %}
```

the best practice is to create  a list view and a detail view  so if you dont know how tell me and i will show you

Comment: thank you so much for the detailed answer, I am trying it right now

Comment: so if I only want to display the points in my HTML, how would I do that? Your code displays the user object

Comment: @boetis inside the the loop : {{x.points }}    , it's  x.your_field_name  and if you named the variable in loop   y  (for y in my_data) its  {{y.your_field_name }}  , go to documentation and serach for template tag  it's very easy  to learn  and there is a  tone of useful template tag

Comment: Hey, I found an easier workaround to this, but I keep getting some stupid error, I am going to update my question with my code, this should work if you can help me resolve the error

Comment: I tried your x method, but it does not show the model in my html

Comment: @boetis yes it did not find a user inside your userdetails model  that matches  the user with the  id that you've provided

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a function to the views.py file and render the HTML file to a URL that should be there in Url Patterns.

For example:
This is a sample model:

```
class C(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=125, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=125, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

This is my views.py

```
from .models import *
def home(request):
    c = C.objects.all()

    return render(request, "<app_name>/index.html", {'c': c})
```

This is my urls.py

```
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('home/',views.home),
 ]
```

This is my part of HTML file where I will show the data

```
{% block content %}
<h2>{{c.name}}</h2>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but your code does not work for me.

Comment: I did not want to loop over the values in my model, i wanted to display only 1 of them

Comment: then you can just use {{key.field}} just like {{c.name}} from the above example